# I have a problem understanding the A* Algorithm (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, a-star

I'm trying to look into the A* Algorithm but I'm kind of having a hard time understanding a specific part. So the A* Algorithm Python Code with the example is this:

```
class Node():
    """A node class for A* Pathfinding"""

    def __init__(self, parent=None, position=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.position = position

        self.g = 0
        self.h = 0
        self.f = 0

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.position == other.position


def astar(maze, start, end):
    """Returns a list of tuples as a path from the given start to the given end in the given maze"""

    # Create start and end node
    start_node = Node(None, start)
    start_node.g = start_node.h = start_node.f = 0
    end_node = Node(None, end)
    end_node.g = end_node.h = end_node.f = 0

    # Initialize both open and closed list
    open_list = []
    closed_list = []

    # Add the start node
    open_list.append(start_node)

    # Loop until you find the end
    while len(open_list) > 0:

        # Get the current node
        current_node = open_list[0]
        current_index = 0
        for index, item in enumerate(open_list):
            if item.f < current_node.f:
                current_node = item
                current_index = index

        # Pop current off open list, add to closed list
        open_list.pop(current_index)
        closed_list.append(current_node)

        # Found the goal
        if current_node == end_node:
            path = []
            current = current_node
            while current is not None:
                path.append(current.position)
                current = current.parent
            return path[::-1] # Return reversed path

        # Generate children
        children = []
        for new_position in [(0, -1), (0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0), (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1)]: # Adjacent squares

            # Get node position
            node_position = (current_node.position[0] + new_position[0], current_node.position[1] + new_position[1])

            # Make sure within range
            if node_position[0] > (len(maze) - 1) or node_position[0] < 0 or node_position[1] > (len(maze[len(maze)-1]) -1) or node_position[1] < 0:
                continue

            # Make sure walkable terrain
            if maze[node_position[0]][node_position[1]] != 0:
                continue

            # Create new node
            new_node = Node(current_node, node_position)

            # Append
            children.append(new_node)

        # Loop through children
        for child in children:

            # Child is on the closed list
            for closed_child in closed_list:
                if child == closed_child:
                    continue

            # Create the f, g, and h values
            child.g = current_node.g + 1
            child.h = ((child.position[0] - end_node.position[0]) ** 2) + ((child.position[1] - end_node.position[1]) ** 2)
            child.f = child.g + child.h

            # Child is already in the open list
            for open_node in open_list:
                if child == open_node and child.g > open_node.g:
                    continue

            # Add the child to the open list
            open_list.append(child)


def main():

    maze = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

    start = (4, 3)
    end = (4, 5)

    path = astar(maze, start, end)
    print(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the

```
for index, item in enumerate(open_list):
    if item.f < current_node.f:
        current_node = item
        current_index = index
```

I don't get how the current_node can be defined as the item in the maze I've given above. In the example I've given above, the start = (4,3) and end = (4,5), giving the only possible shortest distance would be as something like the following:

```
maze = [[0, 0, 0, 0, *, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, *, 1, *, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, *, 1, *, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, *, 1, *, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, s, 1, e, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

with the `s` being the start_node and `e` being the end_node.

However, in the code of the A* Algorithm, the `current_node` becomes the `item` only if the item.f is smaller than the current_node.f. In the example I've given here, I can't see that the first `*` would have an f value smaller than the f value of the `start_node` - I mean, in the code, we already have described the `start_node.f` = 0 haven't we? And we defined the first `current_node` as the `start_node`... so no `item` in the `open_list` would have an item.f value smaller than zero..

How is this possible?? Or am I missing something here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the clue is that you have to take into account the two lines above this for loop as well:

```py
# Get the current node
current_node = open_list[0]
current_index = 0
for index, item in enumerate(open_list):
  if item.f < current_node.f:
    current_node = item
    current_index = index
```

What happens:

- In the **first iteration** of your while loop:

  - There is only one item in the open_list, being the start_node where indeed f=0
  - So after the above code block, this start node becomes the current_node
  - Right after the above loop **the start_node is removed from the open_list**: `open_list.pop(current_index)`
  - The open_list is then populated by the valid neighbouring locations (by walking its children)
- In the **second iteration** of your while loop:

  - The above code block looks for the item in the open_list with the lowest f value
  - because of the first line `current_node = open_list[0]`, you will be sure that **the new current_node is always one from the open_list**.
  - as the start_node has been removed from the open_list, it will for sure be replaced here